# Nginx rewrite image URL to another domain

Tags: nginx, domain, rewrite, url

I have folders structure on the origin server like /images/2020/07/09/imagename.jpg and moved it all to an s3-compatible storage on a subdomain slightly changing folder structure. And now struggling to make correct redirects in case some access the image directly or it has been previously embedded somewhere using the old url.

So the question is how to make Nginx redirect from
https://originsite.com/**images**/2020/07/09/imagename.jpg/png/etc.
to
https://media.originsite.com/**folder**/2020/07/09/imagename.jpg/png/etc.

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your nginx configuration, the following is a best guess.

```
location ~ "^/images/(?<year>[0-9]{4})/(?<month>[0-9]{2})/(?<day>[0-9]{2})/(?<filename>.+\.(?:jpg|png))$" {
    return 301 https://media.originsite.com/foldder/$year/$month/$day/$filename;
}
```

We capture specific parts of the URL path to variables, and then use the variables in forming the actual redirect URL.

The rest of your nginx configuration may affect how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the code @TeroKilkanen but when testing config it returns error:

nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "^/images/(?<year>[0-9]" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/originsite.com.conf:18


The originsite.com config file is https://pastebin.com/qeZqkNiX

Comment: I updated the regex. nginx seems to require quotes around regular expression when it contains quantifiers. BTW. You need to place this before your other `location` block that applies to images. Otherwise this block is never reached.

Comment: Thanks @TeroKilkanen, works like magic!